# StackExchange quiz

Tags: javascript, quiz

I've made a quiz where you get a random question, and you have to guess which StackExchange site it's from.

```js
const optionsCount = 6;
const sitesURL = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?pagesize=999&filter=!SmNU3t0u7kg0gEzR5B';
const questionsURL = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=votes&filter=!bA1d_Kvv2YPQWk';

let game = {
  questionReady: false,
  question: {},
  options: [],
  answer: 0,
  questionsAnswered: 0,
  questionsCorrect: 0,
  sites: []
}

let elements = {
  stats: null,
  question: null,
  options: [],
  next: null
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

function init() {
  elements.stats = document.getElementById('stats');
  elements.question = document.getElementById('question');
  elements.next = document.getElementById('next');
  
  let answers = document.getElementById('answers');
  for(let i = 0; i < optionsCount; i++) {
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', makeGuess.bind(null, i));
    answers.appendChild(button);
    elements.options.push(button);
  }
  
  loadSites().then(chooseQuestion);
}

function loadSites() {
  return fetch(sitesURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      game.sites = data.items.filter(e => e.site_type === "main_site");
    })
}

function loadQuestions(index) {
  return fetch(questionsURL + '&site=' + game.sites[index].api_site_parameter)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      game.sites[index].questions = data.items;
    })
}

async function chooseQuestion() {
  game.options = getOptions(optionsCount, game.sites.length);
  game.answer = randInt(optionsCount);
  game.question = await getQuestion(game.options[game.answer]);
  updateView();
  game.questionReady = true;
}

function getOptions(amount, max) {
  let options = [];
  while(options.length < amount) {
    let value = randInt(max);
    if(!options.includes(value)) {
      options.push(value);
    }
  }
  return options;
}

function randInt(limit) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
}

async function getQuestion(index) {
  if(!game.sites[index].questions) {
    await loadQuestions(index);
  }
  let size = game.sites[index].questions.length;
  return game.sites[index].questions[randInt(size)];
}

function updateView() {
  elements.question.innerHTML = game.question.title;
  for(let i = 0; i < optionsCount; i++) {
    elements.options[i].innerHTML = game.sites[game.options[i]].name;
  }
}

function makeGuess(guess) {
  if(game.questionReady) {
    game.questionsAnswered++;
    if(guess === game.answer) {
      game.questionsCorrect++;
    }
    else {
      elements.options[guess].classList.add('wrong');
    }
    elements.options[game.answer].classList.add('correct');
    elements.next.disabled = false;
    elements.question.setAttribute('href', game.question.link);
    let percent = Math.round(100 * game.questionsCorrect / game.questionsAnswered);
    elements.stats.innerText = `${game.questionsCorrect}/${game.questionsAnswered} - ${percent}%`;
    game.questionReady = false;
  }
}

function onNextClick() {
  elements.question.removeAttribute('href');
  for(option of elements.options) {
    option.classList.remove('correct', 'wrong');
  }
  elements.next.disabled = true;
  chooseQuestion();
}
```

```css
.correct {
  background-color: #54da54;
}
.wrong {
  background-color: #ff6565;
}
#answers button {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p id="stats">0/0 - 0%</p>
<h2><a id="question" target="_blank"></a></h2>
<div id="answers"></div>
<br><br>
<button id="next" onclick="onNextClick()" disabled>Next question</button>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okp7eq93/) if you like fiddling.

It should work in all modern browsers. I've tried to take advantage of some of the newer javaScript features where I could. I'm wondering if I can make the code better, like use of best practices, readability, efficiency, and that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are some very quick comments about a few things I noticed.

### Code style

Consider wrapping your code in an Immediate Invoked Function Expression. This will prevent other code on a page from (accidentally) interacting with your code.

In the following loop you are dropping `option` in the global namespace. Use `const option of elements.options` instead:

```
  for(option of elements.options) {
    option.classList.remove('correct', 'wrong');
  }
```

Consider using `const` more. If you do not intend to re-assign a variable, declaring it `const` will remind you that you are doing something that you did not intend to do in the past. It could also potentially improve performance.

### Error handling

Your code lacks error handling. In particular, if an api call fails, your code will fail on the line with `let size = game.sites[index].questions.length;`. Catch errors and do something accordingly.

### onclick

Don't use `onclick` or any of its siblings as attribute on a html element. (In fact, don't use it in javascript either) Instead, use an `addEventListener` like you already did for your other buttons.